# MacOS Monterey on M1 Macbook SSH limitations

Tags: ssh, apple-silicon, monterey

I have a brand new M1 Max Macbook Pro running Monterey.

I also have an Intel Macbook running Catalina that I migrated to this M1 Macbook from.

Finally, I also have a Linux laptop -- this will become relevant momentarily.

I am a "devops engineer" and frequently open many 10s of SSH connections to remote servers. To make the SSH connections faster I cache them using the SSH options ControlMaster and ControlPath

On the linux laptop, and on the Intel Macbook running SSH to the same set of servers with the **exact** same `~/.ssh/config` file, I can connect to hundreds of servers and don't seem to hit a limit on the SSH ControlPath cached connection sockets.

However, the SSH connections always stop working on the new M1 Macbook once I hit 84 cached connections.

My gut says this is a problem with Monterey, not the M1. Either way, I'm not sure how to resolve it and I haven't found anyone else with this issue.

I probably need to increase some sort of system limit for control sockets. If that's what this is, how do I do that on MacOS Monterey?

Comment: Do you have the option to test your Intel MacBook with Monterey to further troubleshoot the issue (2nd partition or using an external HDD for example)?

Comment: @KevinGrabher no -- I know this is a good idea but I have already wiped that device and I don't intend to crack it back open as it is already packed to be shipped back to my employer